# How to get textbox value using javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I have text box in html. How to get value of text box using id.

My sample single line code is shown below.

```
function testing(){
  // tell the code for text box value id is "testing_id
  console.log(value of textbox)
}
//calling function
testing();
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('testing_id').value`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to retrieve the input-element and then check for the value.

```
document.getElementById('...').value; // This will return the value of the textbox (... should equal the ID of the textbox
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/thijs_s/cf31ob49/

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById`

```
  function testing(){
      console.log(document.getElementById('testing_id').value)
    }
    testing();
```